# Visual Studio 2012 does not reload previously opened XAML files…

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012

…in fact, **none** of the files get reloaded **if any of them was a XAML** file. At the same time, if the opened files did not contain XAML ones, everything gets restored as expected.

To no avail I have tried:

1. Deleting **.SUO** files.
2. Resetting VS2012 General settings.
3. Deleting all the **ViewBookmark** tags from the **CurrentSettings.vssettings** file.

Has anybody experienced the same oddity?

Thanks

Comment: What is your default xaml editor?

Comment: @XAMeLi, good question! I have tried all of them: **XAML UI Designer** and **Automatic Editor Selector** share the same unexpected behavior. Others, like **HTML Editor** or **Source Code (Text) Editor** do reloading fine, but of course, editing XAML with them is worse than using the Notepad.
I am open for more ideas.
Thanks